# How can I calculate the character table for double group in spin-orbit interaction

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

When I read the book(Group theory: application to condensed matter physics by M.S. Dresselhaus, G. Dresselhaus and A. Jorio) page 347, I found I don't know how to derive the new irreducible representations in the double group.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which author?

Comment: M.S. Dresselhaus
G. Dresselhaus
A. Jorio

Comment: I have the same question.